# BIML:cannot bind DerivedColumn output to ADO.Net Destination (simple questuon)

Tags: ssis, biml

Biml trown me next exception when gererating package: 
 
*"EmitSsis. Internal Compiler Error: Workflow EmitSsis contains fatal errors. Phase execution halted. For assistance, please send Biml Compiler error messages to support@varigence.com. See other errors for more information. Exception type: NullReferenceException"* 
 I suppose it caused by the next reason: I try to bind DerivedColumn.Output to ADO.Net Destination and it's output equal NULL. I suppose so then when I'm delete block "DerivedColumn" and on Destination input bound Source Output, all OK.
How to correctly bind output of DerivedColumn to Destination?
Here is part of Biml code

```
 

       <AdoNetSource Name="CompletionCertificate Source" ConnectionName="Connection1">
        <DirectInput> there an SQL query SELECT</DirectInput>
    </AdoNetSource>
    <DerivedColumns Name="Derived1">
        <InputPath OutputPathName="CompletionCertificate Source.Output"/>
        <Columns>
            <Column Name="IsOpeningBalanceStr" SsisDataTypeOverride="DT_BOOL" DataType="String" Length="150">TRIM(IsOpeningBalanceStr) == "1"< /Column>
        </Columns>
    </DerivedColumns>
    <AdoNetDestination Name="CompletionCertificate Destination" ConnectionName="Database (ADO.Net)">
        <InputPath OutputPathName="CompletionCertificate.Output"/>
        <ExternalTableOutput Table="Schema.Table"/>
        <Columns>
        <Column ...
        <Column ...
        <Column ...
        <Columns/>
     </AdoNetDestination >
                     </Transformations>
                 </Dataflow>
             </Tasks>
        </Package>
     </Packages>
 </Biml>
```

Comment: Are you attempting to add a Derived Column to the "regular" output path from the destination or the Error?

Comment: "Regular" output. There was `<InputPath 
 OutputPathName="Derived1.Output"/>`, no `Derived1.ErrorOutput` .

Answer (score 0):

Destination components have no Output path, only Error. You can't connect a Derived Column to the Output path in the SSIS designer for any destination component. That's why the Biml is failing - there's no analog for what you're attempting to do.

The other issue I can see with your code is that you're referencing an invalid source for your input path

```
<AdoNetDestination Name="CompletionCertificate Destination" ConnectionName="Database (ADO.Net)">
    <InputPath OutputPathName="CompletionCertificate.Output"/>
```

That snippet indicates that we should find a predecessor component called `CompletionCertificate` and attach to the Output path. You don't have one of those, you have `CompletionCertificate Source` which is currently routed to a Derived Column called `Derived1`

I think what you're trying to express is that the Destination should be attached to the Derived Column's output path

```
<AdoNetDestination Name="CompletionCertificate Destination" ConnectionName="Database (ADO.Net)">
    <InputPath OutputPathName="Derived1.Output"/>
```

Also, since Biml is a By Convention type of language, the default is to connect things in the order they are declared. Meaning that in the supplied (Source -> Derived Column -> Destination) you don't need to specify any of the pathing since there is no branching to contend with.

Comment: Yes, then I don't define any output paths of Destination. Only `Input Path` of Destination.

Comment: I found reason why it so did. See my answer, @billinkc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a piece of code, where I type miscorrect. Firstly, I have post source code with follow mistake, as told  @billinkc:

```
<AdoNetDestination Name="CompletionCertificate Destination"> <ConnectionName="Database (ADO.Net)">
        <InputPath OutputPathName="CompletionCertificate.Output"/>
```

Right way is `<InputPath OutputPathName="Derived1.Output"/>`. 
But, even this thing is no key idea (with `Derived1.Output` it falls anyway). 
Second, and general reason why exception was thrown, is then I not completely classified a DerivedColumn. Where Column Name defined:

```
 
<Column Name="IsOpeningBalanceStr" SsisDataTypeOverride="DT_BOOL" DataType="String" Length="150"> TRIM(IsOpeningBalanceStr) == "1"</Column>
```

There property `Name` ( *IsOpeningBalanceStr* ), which will going after from DerivedColumn output , have the same Name, like Input value. It is not right. I get wrong its meaning (thought that is Name of Input Column, not Output). 
So, you should to define a property `Name` value  different from an Input Column `Name`. Or your should type ReplaceExisting="true" with other column parametrs. Like that:

`<Column Name="IsOpeningBalance" SsisDataTypeOverride="DT_BOOL" DataType="String" Length="150" ReplaceExisting="true">TRIM(IsOpeningBalanceStr) == "1"</Column>`